# Calcular horas segun 2 fechas datetime-local con Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Buenas stoy usando laravel y Vue, yo tengo 2 fechas que se guardan en mi base de datos, las horas de diferencia entre estas 2 fechas debe ser una variable.
Mis principales dudas es como llamar desde una etiqueta `<td>` a una funcion o tal ves deberia usar otra etiqueta. Si me pueden aconsejar sobre como poder hacer esto.

Yo recorro el array donde estan los registros, tendria que llamar a una funcion por cada vuelta que hace y calcular las horas segun las fechas que les pase, `calcularHoras(registro.inicio,registro.final)`, mi duda es como activar esta función por cada vuelta

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
     <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Inicio</th>
                                    <th>Final</th>
                                    <th>Horas</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="registro in arrayRegistro" :key="registro.id">

                                    <td v-text="registro.inicio"></td>
                                    <td v-text="registro.final"></td>
                                    <td>Aqui debe ir una variable de la hora</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si ya tienes `inicio` y `final` como parte de tu componente ya sea en tu data o props, podrías hacer una `Computed Property` que te calcule la hora.

Comment: Es que soy novato con vue, no se como funciona lo q me comentas, he editado la pregunta ahora está mas clara la duda que presento

Comment: Vale he añadido un v-text en el tercer <td> y dentro he llamado a la funcion. <td v-text="calcularHoras()">

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, a ver que opinan.

Comment: Si, la respuesta esta correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
     <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Inicio</th>
                                    <th>Final</th>
                                    <th>Horas</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="registro in arrayRegistro" :key="registro.id">

                                    <td v-text="registro.inicio"></td>
                                    <td v-text="registro.final"></td>
                                    <td v-text="calcularHoras(registro.inicio,registro.final)"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

`calcularHoras(registro.inicio,registro.final)` Esta funcion calcula la hora y devuelve una variable